# Is Autocorrelation computed with cross-correlation or correlation?

Tags: statistics

I have seen multiple articles online that say that Autocorrelation is computed using correlation and cross-correlation.

Which is autocorrelation actually computed with?

Comment: I would say "cross-correlation" and "correlation" mean the same thing, with "auto-correlation" being the special case of taking the cross-correlation/correlation of a function with itself.

Comment: Ok, Great. Thanks.